# How can I add ajax get call to a html element?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

So I am trying to run a js code that turns all of `<a></a>` elements under another element `<b></b>` (the actual name is unique in the HTML) to a link that makes an HTTP get request. This is what I got and it doesn't do anything.

```js
$("b a").each(function(index, element) {
  var data = element.getAttribute("data-something");
  // $.ajax("https://example.com/" + data);
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b data-something="an-id" class="missing">has has not been installed. to see more click on<a>Link</a></b>
```

Comment: Please add some (valid) HTML to make your situation more clear. What you've shown doesn't have any obvious problems (other than mixing jQuery with raw JavaScript, which adds complexity).

Comment: Also clarify what "a link that makes a request" means. Your code would make the ajax call _immediately_, not on click.

Comment: You want it on click?? `$("b a").on("click", function(){ $.ajax("https://example.com/" + $(this).data("something")); })`

Comment: Hi @isherwood thank you for answering. I am really new to this. I have added the HTLM element that I want to change it is just an HTTP Get request that does something in the background.

Comment: @epascarello I think that is it let me check thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `data-` attribute is not on the `a` element, but on the `b` element. So on link click, you need to get the data from the parent.

Second, you need an event handler on the link.

```js
$("b a").each(function(index, element) {
  let data = element.closest("b").getAttribute("data-something");

  $(element).on("click", function() {
    console.log(data)

    // Commented out for this snippet only
    //$.ajax("https://example.com/" + data);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b data-something="an-id" class=\ "missing\">has has not been installed. to see more click on this <a>Link</a></b><br>
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

The scenario is not clear much.

but you can do it with the below code

```
 $("bg>a").each(function (index, element) {
           var data = element.getAttribute("data-something");
           $.get(("https://example.com/id?" + data);
       });
```